# Nginx multiple domain to one server configurations

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I have 1 app in a server.
[www.mainsite.com/adminindex](http://www.mainsite.com/adminindex)
[www.mainsite.com/landingpage](http://www.mainsite.com/landingpage)

And I would like multiple domains to be able to open this app and still mask/proxy the domain URL using Nginx. But whichever configuration I did, it just redirect, how do set the configuration ?

Let say this is the multiple domains ->
[www.domainsite1.com/adminindex](http://www.domainsite1.com/adminindex)
www.domainsite1/landingpage

[www.domainsite2.com/adminindex](http://www.domainsite2.com/adminindex)
www.domainsite2/landingpage

So when I open

> [www.domainsite1.com/adminindex](http://www.domainsite1.com/adminindex)

, it will open the

> [www.mainsite.com/adminindex](http://www.mainsite.com/adminindex)

but the URL stays the same

> **[www.domainsite1.com/adminindex](http://www.domainsite1.com/adminindex)**

.

I have already set domainsite1 A record to the Nginx IP.
This is my current Nginx configuration :

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  #listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.domainsite1.com/;

   location / {
     #  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
     #  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     #  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     #  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_pass   https://www.mainsite.com/index;
     # Add the trailing slash
     # rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    }
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  #listen 443 ssl;
  server_name www.domainsite2.com/;

  location / {
    #  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    #  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    #  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    #  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass   https://www.mainsite.com/index;
    # Add the trailing slash
    # rewrite ^([^.]*[^/])$ $1/ permanent;
    }
 }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If only your domain name is different and you would like to resolve it to several address with no changes in `uri`, You can use this just keep domain name in `proxy_pass` with `/`

No matter what is the domain name, it will eventualy resolve to -

- `www.example.com/xxxx/`    -> `/xxxx/` -> `https://www.mainsite.com/xxxx`
- `www.exampletwo.com/yyyy/` -> `/yyyy/` -> `https://www.mainsite.com/yyyy`
- `ww.examplethree.com`, -> `/` -> `https://www.mainsite.com/`

```
/ {
    .
    .
    proxy_pass   https://www.mainsite.com/;
    }
```

If you would like to know more info - [Link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass)